# Dynamically change d3js/SVG arc parameters

Tags: jquery, d3.js, dynamic

I am creating a graph, using jQuery & d3js. 
Using jQuery, I've created a scope slider, which I aim to use the values from to dynamically adjust the scope of the graph.

```
var canvasheight = 800;
var canvaswidth = 1500;
$(document).ready(function(){
// Canvas
var svgContainer = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('id', 'svgContainer')
  .attr('height', canvasheight)
  .attr('width', canvaswidth);
var curve = svgContainer.append('path')        
  .attr('id', "curve")
  .attr('d', "M 500,500 a1000,1000 0 0,1 500,0")
  .attr('style', "fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width:6");
```

I want to use variable substitution to change the 'path' string:
`"M 500,500 aVal1,Val2 0 0,1 500,0"`, so as I change the slider, I can also change the variables Val1 & Val2!

How do I do it?

Inthe slider 'resize' function I tried:
`curve.attr("d", "M 500,500 a" + scopep + "," + scopep + " 0 0,1 500,0");`
but that didn't work!?!?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the code you provided, are you sure that `scopep` is a valid value? Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/oybzkzue/), where if you click anywhere in the SVG it will update the arc.

Comment: I changed it from: `curve.attr("d", "M 500,500 a" + yval + "," + yval + " 0 0,1 500,0");` to `$( "#curve" ).attr('d', "M 500,500 a"+yval+","+yval+" 0 0,1 500,0");`  which made it functional for me